# OpenCV mat concatenation of a matrix with a zero matrix in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to pad a matrix vertically with zeros at the top and bottom.

But this code fails with an CV_Assert because padding is "empty", that is filled with zeros:

```
cv::Mat dataMat;
//...
cv::Mat padding(dataMat.rows, dataMat.cols, datumMat.type(), 0);
std::vector<cv::Mat> matrices;
matrices.push_back(padding);
matrices.push_back(dataMat);
matrices.push_back(padding);
cv::Mat resultMat;
cv::vconcat(matrices, resultMat);
```

Is there a way to use vconcat to pad with zero matrices or do I have to copy-paste and hack vconcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`copyMakeBorder`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder):

```
int top_padding = 3;
int bottom_padding = 3;
copyMakeBorder(dataMat, dataMat, top_padding, bottom_padding, 0, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0,0,0,0));
```

---

If you want to zero-initialize a matrix without knowing the type at compile time, you should use [`zeros`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=zeros#mat-zeros):

```
Mat padding = Mat::zeros(dataMat.rows, dataMat.cols, datumMat.type());
```

Comment: If Mat:: padding = Mat::zeros (...), padding.empty() == true.

Comment: Please show the actual code. This doesn't make much sense

Comment: Mat padding = Mat::zeros(dataMat.rows, dataMat.cols, datumMat.type());
if (padding.empty()) { cout << "true"; }  // This prints true.

Comment: If padding results to be empty, can be only because dataMat is empty. Please check that dataMat is in fact non-empty